# Iteration through linked list recursively

Tags: c++

In this piece of code

```
Node* insert(int num, Node *head) {
 if (head == NULL|| num <= head->next)
      return addNewNode(num, head);

   head->next = insert(num, head->next);
   return head;
}
```

Why is it

```
head->next = insert(num,head->next);
```

and not

```
head = insert(num,head->next);
```

I understand we have to traverse through the singly linked list and I thought "head->next" inside the function call takes care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't insert the element as the first node, you want to keep the head and insert into the list's tail.

`head->next = insert(num, head->next);` replaces the tail with the modified one.

`head = insert(num, head->next);` would ignore the head and replace it with the result of inserting an element in its tail.

Example: say that we have

```
head
 |
 v
 1 -> 3 -> X
```

and want to insert 2.

The recursive insertion returns a pointer to

```
2 -> 3 -> X
```

and pointing `head->next` at this gives

```
head
 |
 v
 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> X
```

while your suggestion would give

```
    head
     |
     v
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> X
```

and you've lost the 1.